# I am getting issue in dependencies and packages. Where should I upgrade web, meta, and material_colo_utilities packages?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-lints

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...
  flutter_lints 2.0.3 (3.0.1 available)
  lints 2.1.1 (3.0.0 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.10.0 (1.11.0 available)
  web 0.3.0 (0.4.0 available)
Got dependencies!
5 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have tried to `pub get` the dependencies flutter in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

This solution involves a few steps:

1. Update on pubspec.yml the version of `flutter_lints` from `^2.0.1` to `^3.0.1`.
2. Run `flutter pub get`. Now you should have only the warnings related to `web`, `meta` and `material_color_utilities`.
3. Run `flutter update-packages --force-upgrade`. This should fix `web`& `meta` versions.
4. Wait for the next Flutter release. It seems `material_color_utilities` is hard coded in `flutter_test` dependencies and already updated on `main`, so updating Flutter in the next release it should be fixed. (reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/139457)

Answer (score 0):

1.Open your directory and run `flutter pub outdated`

2.Run `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`